# Thesis Template

Tags: templates, thesis, engineering

I'm currently trying to setup a template like from [Siarhei Khirevich's site](http://www.khirevich.com/latex/page_layout/).
The person responsible for setting up the site has done a great job of giving advice on how to set up your template, but basically I am very new to latex. And I am struggling with it.
Could anyone here advise me on how to set up my template to resemble something like [this photo](http://www.khirevich.com/latex/page_layout/Page_layout_thesis_photo_large.jpg)?

Any input appreciated

MWE from comment:

```
{\textendash={400,400}, % en-dash, add more space around it
"28={ ,150}, % left bracket, add space from right
"29={150, }, % right bracket, add space from left
\textquotedblleft={ ,150}, % left quotation mark, space from right
\textquotedblright={150, }} % right quotation mark, space from left

\SetExtraKerning[unit=space]
{encoding={*}, family={qhv}, series={b}, size={large,Large}}
{1={-200,-200}, 
    \textendash={400,400}}

\usepackage[tracking=true]{microtype}
\SetTracking{encoding={*}, shape=sc}{40}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{ {images/} }
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage[a4paper,width=150mm,top=25mm,bottom=25mm,bindingoffset=6mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead{}
\fancyhead[RO,LE]{Thesis Title}
\fancyfoot{}
\fancyfoot[LE,RO]{\thepage}
\fancyfoot[LO,CE]{Chapter \thechapter}
\fancyfoot[CO,RE]{Author Name}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}

\usepackage[style=authoryear,sorting=none]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{references.bib}

\hbadness=10000
\hfuzz=50pt

\begin{document}

\include{titlepage}

\newpage
\begin{tabbing}
    1.  Supervisor: \= Dr. ......    \\
    \>  \= Mechanical, Aeronautical \& Biomedical Department\\
    \>  \= University \emph{of} ..... \\
    \>  \= ..... \\
\end{tabbing}

\vspace{10mm}
Supervisor's signature: \_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_

\vspace{20mm}
\begin{tabbing}
    2. Second Reader: \= Dr. .....    \\
    \>  \= Mechanical, Aeronautical \& Biomedical Department\\
    \>  \= University \emph{of} ..... \\
    \>  \= .... \\
\end{tabbing}

\vspace{10mm}
Second Reader's signature: \_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_


\include{Abstract}

\include{Declaration}

\include{Acknowledgements}

\include{Dedication}

\microtypesetup{protrusion=false} % disables protrusion locally in the document
\tableofcontents
\microtypesetup{protrusion=true} % enables protrusion

\listoffigures

\listoftables

\chapter{Introduction}
\input{chapters/introduction}

\chapter{Literature Review}
\input{chapters/chapter02}

\chapter{Theory}
\input{chapters/chapter03}

\chapter{Computational Modelling}
\input{chapters/chapter04}

\chapter{Results and Discussion}
\input{chapters/chapter05}

\chapter{Conclusions and Future Works}
\input{chapters/chapter06}

\chapter*{References}


\appendix
\chapter{Turnitin Originality Report}

\chapter{Computational Modelling}

\chapter{Physics Setup}

\end{document}
```

Comment: But please use the `BCOR` (binding correction) option of `typearea` instead of the code used to shift the text around.

Comment: Hi Kurt, thanks for the welcome. Sorry about not putting my current example up initially, here it is,  \documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[hmargin=2.5cm,vmargin=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr} 
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{url}
\begin{document}
\lhead{......}
\rhead{.....}
\chead{FYP REPORT}
\begin{titlepage}
\begin{center}
\vspace{5in}
\begin{figure}[H]
\begin{center}
\includegraphics[width=400pt]{.....}
\end{center}
\end{figure}
\begin{LARGE}
Final Year Project
\\

Comment: As you can see, im very new to this, I completed some good reports using latex during the year but this is alot bigger but I'd like to give it a go. I've tried adding in bits from the website above but I keep getting errors

Comment: Ok thanks for the patience Kurt, after a few hours of chopping and changing I have come up with the above.

Comment: Ok thanks for the patience Kurt, after a few hours of chopping and changing I have come up with the above. It runs fine and is looking pretty close but maybe you can help with my issues. Currently when compiled the pages look off to the right of page, I wish for them to be alternate for two page printing and leaving even space from binding. Also the margins on the top and bottom are very tight. I would also like to have the chapter no. and name on left page header centered, while the section no. and title is on the righthand page header centered.

Comment: Also how could I remove the footer, leaving bottom of pages blank, with the page numbers in the headers, left corner for left page, right corner for right page

Comment: Please note that the site has a one question per question, zero new question per comment policy. Right now, your code cannot be compiled as it lacks a class. Please test your code before posting it. Also, nobody can compile it since it requires a bunch of files on your computer.

Comment: A remark: I think the line length is too big for a Thesis. You should definitely take a look at [`classicthesis`](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/classicthesis/).

Comment: Regarding your questions about removing the footer and page numbers in the header: You *need* to read the documentation of [`fancyhdr`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/fancyhdr). All your questions are answered there. It boils down to use `\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead{}
\fancyhead[CE]{\slshape \leftmark}
\fancyhead[CO]{\slshape \rightmark}
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\thepage}` as described on page 8 of the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

Rule of thumb, load as many packages as needed, but as few as possible.

The following uses standard KOMA-book including a font package for another font, `mathtools` for some `amsmath` fixes and `biblatex` for citing. This should be all you need right now.

Further packages you should keep in the back of your head:

- `chemformula` for chemistry
- `siunitx` for typesetting units
- `babel` for right localization and hyphenation
- `booktabs` to generate nice tables after having read the doc
  ... some more, depending on what you want to do

---

We need a page, chapter and section headings and a header. A bit
of math and some fonts. All this can be found in *any*
introduction to LaTeX.

```
\documentclass[fleqn,chapterprefix=true,headsepline]{scrbook}
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}%header
\clearpairofpagestyles
\cehead{\leftmark}
\cohead{\rightmark}
\ohead*{\pagemark}
\addtokomafont{pagehead}{\upshape}
\usepackage{libertine}%text font
\usepackage[libertine]{newtxmath}%a bit matching math
\usepackage{mathtools}%nice math
\usepackage[style=authoryear]{biblatex}%citing 
\usepackage{blindtext}%dummy text
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
\begin{document}
\chapter{Sarah is crazy}
\blindtext 
\begin{equation}
    \gamma = \frac{1}{\tau} = \frac{D_\text{eff}}{D_\text{m}}
\end{equation}
as defined by someone different than Frank\footfullcite{companion}

\blindtext[8]
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

Many more information can be found in the documentation to the base class `scrguien` and the corresponding packages.